# Divergence in spherical coordinates as can be done in W|A

Tags: vector-calculus

Is there any widget kind of thing that can work out calculations of vector analysis in not-Cartesiian coordinates, i.e spherical and cylindrical?

Like the calculators found here:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/VectorAnalysis.html

Answer (score 1):

You want divergence widget?  I has `Div`, is better:

```
Div[{f[r], 0, 0}, {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"]
(* 2 f[r]/r + f'[r] *)
```

Is divergence of spherically symmetric central field $f(r)\hat r$.